# Fitness trampoline - what is the advantage?

Tags: cardio, home-exercise

I'm looking for possibilities to do a intensive cardio training at home. Someone advised me to buy a fitness trampoline which actually surprised me a little.

I would like to know the additional advantage of a fitness trampoline in comparison to more classic cardio exercises like a cross trainer.

I'm surprised that fitness trampolines aren't mentioned a lot on SE.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking at cardio? Leg workout? Core? Reducing injury? Are you looking to jump? Jog? I discussed the use of a small trampoline a bit at https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/27873/safe-use-of-minitramp-to-develop-hip-and-lower-leg-for-mobility-in-older-decondi/27890#27890, but I don't know if that's the same s what you're looking for.

Comment: @SeanDuggan, thanks for your time and I read your post. I'm looking for a cardio workout at home with little injury chance. I'm not sure a trampoline is the right choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fitness trampoline with knee injuries doesn't sound like the best idea to me. Although the trampoline springs cushion and absorb force your knee can still take pressure which can be dangerous. You don't want to redevelop previously existing injuries.

However the answer to your question - A fitness trampoline can be good for your upper body as well as lower, not to mention cardio. Depending on the intensity in which you use it, it does have many benefits.

However cardio is cardio, whatever you choose to do. As long as you up the intensity and push yourself like anything in fitness, results will follow if you follow the basic disciplines, diet, consistency etc.. so whatever you prefer is what you should pick as it helps you to remain motivated. If you want to jump - then buy a trampoline, if you want to run - Maybe a treadmill or even go for a run outside, if you enjoy the cross trainer - then buy a cross trainer etc etc...

Comment: @3TW3 If you're trying to avoid knee injury cross trainer would likely be most efficient for your situation

Comment: Ok I will certainly take this into account, ty

Answer (score 1):

The trampoline's advantage is the lack of jarring impact.

A small round fitness trampoline will have an edge effect:  Your foot is not in the centre of the trampoline on the bounce, and so there is some sideways torque.  If road cambers bother you when running, this may have an effect here.

A larger trampoline doesn't show this effect.

A large decent quality garden trampoline is an excellent workout and a lot of fun.  I can max out my heart rate in about 80 seconds.  But you aren't jogging on it.  You do a bunch of jumps, and turns, land on stomach, hands and knees, back, butt.

If you do this, take lessons before you try flips.  Most of the injuries you can do to yourself while being rightside up range from sprains to dislocations to bone breaks if you work at it.  Flips can break your neck